# Display json api data in html

Tags: php, html, json, api

I have a json API key and I'm trying to get the "balance" value of the XXXX-102 account but I can not do it, can you help me?
I would like to display it on an html page

This is the API key I have: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eqohltkxjawadsy/Screenshot%202019-01-26%2019.37.29.png?dl=0

Link API: https://www.example.com/it/user/ApiWhsGetSubList?email=mymail@gmail.com&apikey=XXXX

Comment: not sure to understand, you are asking for a complete javascript and html code to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "balance" key in your result. Might it be "credit" what you are looking for?

```
$apiResult = json_decode($yourJsonString);
($apiResult['status'] !== 'ok') && 
  trigger_error('Unexpected API Result');

empty(($account = array_filter($apiResult['result'], function($item) {
  return $item['account'] === 'XXXX-102';
}))) && trigger_error('Account not found.');

echo $account[0]['credit'];
```

Comment: Thank you very so much!

Answer (score 0):

Look into [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Then you can access it like a regular PHP-array afterwards. Like this;

```
$php_array = json_decode( $YOUR_JSON_API_KEY );
echo $php_array['balance'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode($json_data); 
print_r($data->result[0]->billing);

foreach ($data->result as $item) {
    echo $item->billing; 
}
```

You can access all billing details through this foreach loop.